# Getting Notification after a certain time in Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Hello i am completely beginner in android, trying to make a application which will fetch event name with date and time from Google Calendar. After that it should send a notification before 2 hours of that event.
Issue is i am not getting how to fetch event and show in Notifiaction.

This are My code.
CalendarFetch

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implementsEasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    private TextView mOutputText;
    private Button mCallApiButton;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;

    private static final String BUTTON_TEXT = "Call Google Calendar API";
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = { CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mCallApiButton = new Button(this);
        mCallApiButton.setText(BUTTON_TEXT);
        mCallApiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallApiButton.setEnabled(false);
                mOutputText.setText("");
                getResultsFromApi();
                mCallApiButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        activityLayout.addView(mCallApiButton);

        mOutputText = new TextView(this);
        mOutputText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
        mOutputText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        mOutputText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mOutputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        mOutputText.setText(
                "Click the \'" + BUTTON_TEXT +"\' button to test the API.");
        activityLayout.addView(mOutputText);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Calendar API ...");

        setContentView(activityLayout);

        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
    }

    private void getResultsFromApi() {
        if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            acquireGooglePlayServices();
        } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
            mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
        } else {
            new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
        }
    }

    @AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void chooseAccount() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
            String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                getResultsFromApi();
            } else {
                // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
                startActivityForResult(
                        mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
        } else {
            // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    mOutputText.setText(
                            "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                                    "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.");
                } else {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        getResultsFromApi();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    /**
     * Callback for when a permission is granted using the EasyPermissions
     * library.
     * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
     *         permission
     * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
     * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
     */
    private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
        }
    }
    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
                MainActivity.this,
                connectionStatusCode,
                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        dialog.show();
    }

    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }


        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
            DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
            Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .setTimeMin(now)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute();
            List<Event> items = events.getItems();

            for (Event event : items) {
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                    // the start date.
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                eventStrings.add(
                        String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
            }
            return eventStrings;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Calendar API:");
                mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                            + mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is simple code from Google official Calendar API, and it is working fine but i don't want to show this in Notification 
My Notification code.

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setAction(MainActivity.MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
    intent.putExtra("message",message);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Battery Level")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

How can i show those events in Notification. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try to limit the amount of code. I don't think someone would preview such amount of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) or [JobScheduler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdINLG5QrJc) to subscribe event that will be started at your specified time.

**Edited**

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Actually instead of setting 8:30 a.m. you can set any date.

Comment: Your answer should rely on external urls. Even Google can change them for any reason. What if they moved all the documentation to dev.android...?

Comment: Can you tell me some examples of AlarmManager. How to start a event using AlarmManager please

Comment: @xenteros this is my First time using StackOverflow